# Debian 12 Bookworm PCIe Bus Errors for Intel 7265 Wireless Adapter

Tags: debian, wifi, pci

In a new installation of Debian 12 Bookworm on HP ProDesk 600 G2 Mini i5-6500T with the Intel 7265 wireless adapter. I receive a message every 10 seconds or so in dmesg, which I suspect is related to the wireless card.

```
[Mon Jan 29 03:28:12 2024] 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[Mon Jan 29 03:28:12 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID) 
[Mon Jan 29 03:28:12 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: device [8086:a115] error status/mask=000000001/00002000 
[Mon Jan 29 03:28:12 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: [ 0 ] RxErr (First)
```

Which is the PCIe Bridge...

```
00:1c.0 PCI Bridge: Intel corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
```

While investigating I found that the message doesn't appear when wireless networking is disabled. Which leads me to suspect there is a problem with the wireless adapter.

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [Stone Peak 2 AC]
Kernal driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernal modules: iwlwifi
```

The PCIe device seems to be working although I have only tested wifi. I installed Debian 12 with the net installer over the network after purchasing the device which was previously running windows, so the adapter is working.

Kernal Version `6.1.0-17-amd64`

I have enabled non-free repository and installed linux-firmware-nonfree but the messages are still occuring. I do think the PCIe device may need reseating following transit but have not attempted to reseat it just yet as it is in a difficult position and I suspect this could be a software issue s the adapter is working.

I have also updated the BIOS of the system and tried enabling/disabling ASPM for the device to no avail. Should I be concerned about these messages? I have also observed a few times that there have been AER errors produced in dmesg on the same device which doesn't seem to affect functionality.

The device is the HP ProDesk 600 G2 Mini i5-6500T mini with the intel 7265 wireless PCIe adapter. Any suggestions on resolving this issue or is it a non-issue / benign problem? Interested to hear your thoughts on the error, the card seems to be working but is producing PCIe Bus Error every ten seconds while wifi is active. My concern is if I leave the WiFi on the log file could grow exponentially and cause unnecessary disk space consumption.